# How properly addObserver in UITextField subclass for getting when Keyboard is visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have subclass of `UITextField`. I want to know when keyboard is visible. This will help me to move all view up if the keyboard is hiding my text field.

In my subclass I add observer as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardIsVisible:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I expect to catch the size of the keyboard:

```
/* Get height when keyboard is visible */
- (void)keyboardIsVisible:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];

    _keyboardHeight =keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;

}
```

I will use ivar `_keyboardHeight` to decide if I have to move keyboard:

```
/* Move keyboard */
-(void)showKeyboardWithMove {

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    ////CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;


    if (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height > screenHeight - _keyboardHeight) {
        double offset = screenHeight - _keyboardHeight - self.frame.origin.y - self.frame.size.height;
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, offset, self.superview.frame.size.width, self.superview.frame.size.height);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

        self.superview.frame = rect;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

From my view controller class I call `showKeyboardWithMove`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(MyCustomTextField *)textField
{
    // Call method for moving control when Keyboard is shown and hides it
    [textField showKeyboardWithMove];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(MyCustomTextField *)textField
{
    // Call method for returning control when Keyboard is hidden
    [textField hideKeyboardWithMove];
}
```

The problem is that `keyboardIsVisible` is not fire when I first show keyboard. So I think that my observer is not properly coded. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardIsVisible:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

to viewWillAppear. In my case it works.
Also I use

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
```

instead of

```
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
```

Comment: it does not working. When I move `addObserver` to `viewWillAppear`, observer is not set at all.

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c

To move your view up, when keyboard was visible can be done by multiple ways, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

In Swift:

Add the following two definition in viewDidLoad() function first:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

and then add the following two methods in your class.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {    
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```